# How to loop through object return by SQLALchemy and process each row and display it to HTML

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following code in my views.py which works fine and i can see result in the HTML page

## views.py

```
def listallcams():
    emptlist = [] # an empty list for holding processing record values
    camtab = SVSIpCamReg.query.filter_by(u_id = current_user.id).all()
    for rec in camtab:
        dkey = rec.key
        bdkey=bytes(dkey)
        f = Fernet(bdkey)
        bcamurl = bytes(rec.camurl_hash)
        camurl =f.decrypt(bcamurl)
        emptlist.append(camurl) #0
        emptlist.append(rec.sview) #1
        emptlist.append(rec.camregdate) #2
        emptlist.append(rec.sitename) #3
    return render_template('cam/viewallcam.html',allcam = emptlist)
```

## Html template page

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}
    List of all register cams
    {% endblock %}
    {%block page_content%}
    <ul class="lead"><h3>Your Registered Cams List are here:</h3>
    {% for cam in allcam %}
    <li class="lead">
     When Cam was added:-{{ moment(cam.camregdate).fromNow() }}<br>
        <a href="{{ url_for('main.user', emid=cam.camusername.emid) }}">  {{ cam.camusername.fname }}</a><br>

    <b>Location of Camera Site:</b> 
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{ cam.sitename}}">{{ cam.sitename }}</a>
<br>


            <b>Camera Viewing Window Size:</b>{{ cam.sview }}<br>
            <b>Camera URL:-</b>{{ cam.camurl_hash }}

    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {%endblock%}
```

After executing this page i am not getting any records in the page.

Now i have some need of manipulating this rows data before i send it to HTML page. In such case i have forloop in flask code which can iterate through this object and i can put my row manipulation code inside this forloop which works as expected.

Now  when i have more than once record to process it  and how would i store processed rows from for loops and then send them to the html page to display it.

While i was debug this code the SVSobj of model class has rows as list.

Is there anyway where i can easily iterate through number rows returned by SQLAlchemy query and then processed it and send them back to HTML page.(Cursor like in normal application)

Sorry for asking such naive question but it is hunting me down from long time.

I really appreciate your time and research on this

Comment: In your processing you are adding each parameter to the list, and not an object. In your HTML you are trying to access parameters from an object. You think your list will look like [ camera_object1, camera_object2, etc..] while it actually contains [camurl1, sview, etc.. ] try to just display the cam object in the html and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Zyber for update ...   can you giv eme an example like how should i display cam object while debug i can see my empty list variable become like this ['http://192.168.1.5/live', u'70*80', datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 7, 11, 3, 40, 261000), u'NiravHome',
'http://192.168.1.5/live', u'22*59', datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 7, 18, 25, 51, 655000), u'23.062705,72.544326']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
def listallcams():
   camtab = SVSIpCamReg.query.filter_by(u_id = current_user.id).all()
   for rec in camtab:
      dkey = rec.key
      bdkey=bytes(dkey)
      f = Fernet(bdkey)
      bcamurl = bytes(rec.camurl_hash)
      camurl =f.decrypt(bcamurl)
      rec.camurl = camurl
   return render_template('cam/viewallcam.html',allcam = camtab)
```

What we are trying to achieve is that we fetch the cameras we are interested in. We then loop through them, and add one attribute to each object(the attribute "camurl")

After this you should now be able to use the objects in your html.

```
{% for cam in allcam %}
   <p>{{ cam.camurl }}</p>
   <p>{{ cam.sitename }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Zyber thanks for your reply i did include your code in HTML but it shows me only  cam.camurl in loop i guess we need access the value 
cam.sitename
cam.camurl
cam.sitename
cam.camurl
cam.sitename
cam.camurl

Comment: @NiravJoshi I forgot to add brackets around the variables in the for loop, I've updated the post.

Comment: Hi Zyber i got your point sorry i also missed it Your code does work excellent in the end what is happening once page rendering is done i can see all the URL but in the database it update hash into plain text url ... i am not sure why it is updating table column called camurl              camurl =f.decrypt(bcamurl)
      rec.camurl = camurl

Comment: Thank you very much Zyber you made my day ... Many thanks your solution work like charm... .thanks a lot... have a nice day.